# How to mute AVAudioPlayer if music from another app is playing in spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

By default, I notice that in Spritekit, if audio from another app is playing, it is automatically turned off and the audio in the app plays. How do I make it so that the opposite occurs? How do I make it so that the audio and music and sound effects in the app remain mute and external music plays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AVAudioSession` to adjust the mixing settings. There are few possible audio categories you can choose, but I think `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` is probably closest to what you want:

```
NSError *err;
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&err];

if (err) {
    NSLog(@"There was a problem setting the session category: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however, the in-app music and sound is not muted, instead music from both the app and the external app is playing simultaneously

Comment: Yes; that's the closest category that exists. You have two other options: try reading the `secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` property of your `AVAudioSession`, but if that fails you might need to read the `otherAudioPlaying` property instead. Technically you should use the former rather than the latter, but they do ever so slightly different things so you might need to try both.

Comment: (Note: this requires *you* to do the checking, i.e. you check the conditions and play a sound only if appropriate.)